# SQL Checking a date range without using the BETWEEN operator

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

I have this query:

```
Select * 
From Rezervari 
   Join Clienti ON Rezervari.Codcl=Clienti.Codcl 
where Rezervari.Data BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017/01/01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2017/01/10', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

It throws this error inside SQL Developer:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I need to do the same thing after getting this fixed, without using the BETWEEN SQL Operator.

Here is my table structure:

```
Clienti:
Name       Null     Type         
---------- -------- ------------ 
CODCL      NOT NULL NUMBER(33)   
LOCALITATE          VARCHAR2(33) 
NUME                VARCHAR2(33) 
CNP                 NUMBER(33)   
ADRESA              VARCHAR2(33) 
DISCOUNT            VARCHAR2(33)

Rezervari:
Name   Null     Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
NRREZ  NOT NULL NUMBER(33)   
CODCL  NOT NULL NUMBER(33)   
DATA            VARCHAR2(33) 
NRZILE          NUMBER(33)   
NRCAM           NUMBER(33)
```

Comment: If `Data` is a date value then store it as such, not as a string.

Comment: Either provide `YYYY/MM/DD` as 2nd parameter, or pass the first parameter as `2017-01-01`

Comment: If anybody tries to select `TO_DATE('2017/01/01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` he'll see that it's worked :)

Comment: I did 'TO_DATE(Rezervari.Data, 'DD/MM/YYYY')', so converting the string to a date, now it works, thanks everyone :D

Comment: Why on earth are you storing DATE values in a VARCHAR column?

Comment: It's not my db schema, it is in my assignments for an oracle course. I altered the table anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a date and compare it to dates:

```
where to_date(rezervari.data,'DD/MM/YYYY') between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-01-10'
```

It looks as though it would be better stored as an actual `date`, so perhaps a longer term project would be to change the table.

Answer (score 1):

*You tried to enter a date value, but the date entered did not match the date format(Reason for getting ORA-01830)*.

Format mask is not important whether `-` or `/`, the important thing is to convert a string to a date value:

```
to_date(Rezervari.Data,'YYYY/MM/DD') 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-01-01', 'YYYY/MM/DD') AND TO_DATE('2017/01/10', 'YYYY.MM.DD')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're trying to compare VARCHAR field (Rezervari.data) with the date value. Such things with implicit type conversions leads to many errors; at least result of this query depends of current NLS settings and thus leads to ORA-1830 you got.
2. You can freely replace `a between b and c` with `a >= b and a <= c`, but I cannot imagine any reason to do this.